# Если применить Pattern.compile("\\[\\s*([0-9.]*)\\s*;\\s*([0-9.]*)\\s*\\]") к "[12.4;34.6]" то получим цифры. Как удалось не выводить скобки?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Это рабочий пример. Но я его не понимаю.
1) Объясните пожалуйста, как удалось добиться того что скобки [ не выбираются а отбираются только цифры из них? \[ означает найти скобку но не брать ее что ли?
2) И как изменить регулярное выражение чтоб оно пропускало ( такие скобки? Те из любых скобок чтоб выбирались только цифры.  Видимо надо добавить что то вроде \( в регулярное выражение через или.
При вводе [12.4;34.6] или этого (12.4;34.6) ответ должен быть одинаковый.

```
public class Test {
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\[\\s*([0-
9.]*)\\s*;\\s*([0-9.]*)\\s*\\]");

public static void main(String[] args) {
String text = "[12.4;34.6]";
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(text);
System.out.println(match.matches());
System.out.println(match.group(1));
System.out.println(match.group(2));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объясню так, это ответ сразу на два вопроса:

Если допустим работать с RegEx'ом `"!(.*(\\w+).*)!"` и строкой `"Привет !   друг  !"`, то после команды `.find()` на вывод можно отправить 3 строки:
1) `.group()` или `.group(0)` что является тем же самым! Это нулевая группа, т.е. полное совпадение: `"!   друг  !"`
2) `.group(1)` это то, что во внешних круглых скобках, это считается первой группой (см. тему группы в RegEx'ах), получишь: `"   друг  "`
3)Ну и понятно, что `.group(2)` даст тебе: `"друг"`. Это вторая группа, всё то, что во внутренних скобках.

А то, что в твоём примере `\\[`, так это просто потому, что `[` -- служебный символ, для создания символьных классов в духе `[a-z]` (все маленькие английские буквы)

Заметь что в исходном RegEx'е, круглые скобки `(` и `)` -- это тоже служебные символы! Просто любой RegEx (ну или Pattern) может состоять из групп в духе
`0    (1 )   (2    (3)   (4  )  )` -- Вот так считаются группы, и на вывод от `.group(n)` ты получишь только тот кусочек совпадения, который попал в энную группу.

Answer (score 3):

1) Скобки это спецсимволы, экранирование \ используется наоборот, как раз для того, чтобы искало скобки в тексте. Квадратные скобки - спецсимвол диапазона. Круглые скобки - спецсимвол группы.
2) Выводит только цифры потому, что group(1) - это означает вывести первую группу. Группа - та часть выражения, что в круглых скобках. В частности, ([0-9.]*) означает любое число из диапазона от 0 до 9, повторяющееся любое количество раз, является группой.

Comment: "`([0-9.]*)`" - про точку забыли в описании

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо. Тогда мне надо сделать так - Pattern.compile("(\[|\()\s*(-?[0-9.]*)\s*;\s*(-?[0-9.]*)\s*(\]|\))"); Те добавить группу в начало (\[|\() и в конце (\[|\)).И учитывать при выводе что нумерация групп сдвинулась так как появилась новая первая